# When I run "sudo compiz" on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-unity

unity.debug.interface DebugDBusInterface.cpp:216 Unable to load entry point in libxpathselect: libxpathselect.so.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
WARN  2017-07-04 09:07:31 unity :0 Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Those are the final two errors/warnings. Maybe I meant the final error/warning but that's ok.
I am using VCXSrv on Windows 10 Home on a Dell Inspiron 1545. Yes, that product is not tested for Windows 10 upgrade.

Comment: Why doesn't Microsoft give graphical user interface to WSL? What's so useful about WSL if there is no GUI? That's boring with jus text. Is Microsoft just trying to make money? That's not what it's about. Why should Microsoft make it slower to discourage use? Anyway, if Linux grows in popularity (and therefore eats Microsoft's lunch), Microsoft might add a Linux subsystem to stay in the market, as people will use GNU on Windows.

Comment: It's intended for developers and other IT professionals.

Comment: I'd rather have UNIX subsystem for POSIX compliance, because GNU/Linux is just a kind of UNIX-based system. There are many others. I'd use the general UNIX subsystem for compliance, and Linux for regular use, because just a Linux subsystem won't support [non-Linux] UNIX systems and therefore not general POSIX.

Comment: @Jonathan Dahling: They have to start somewhere and I'd prefer a working command line interface over a broken GUI every day, and especially for development purposes (which is what this feature is about). And of course they want to make money with it. It profit orientated company that has to pay the developers working on it.

Comment: I think I made a discovery. You don't use sudo for that. You use gnomesu or something. Try "gnomesu compiz." What's the Unity equivalent to gnomesu?